# how to validate date must not less than one year from two dates

Tags: javascript, validation

```
var startDate = $('#txt_fromDate').val(from);//startdate
var endDate =   $('#txt_toDate').val(to);//enddate
var ndays;
ndays = (startDate - endDate) / 1000 / 86400;
ndays = Math.round(ndays - 0.5);
alert(ndays);
if(ndays<365){
    alert("gap must be at least one year");
}
```

*how to validate date must not within one year*

Comment: What is the format of `startDate` and `endDate` ?

Comment: What is the result of this ? What are the value of startDate/endDate ?

Answer (score 0):

inlcude moment.js file.

```
        var startDate = $('#txt_fromDate').val(from);//from date
        var endDate =   $('#txt_toDate').val(to);//end date

        if (moment(startDate).add(1, 'y').isAfter(
                moment(endDate)) === true) {
            // To + 1 year is after from
            alert("Academic Gap must atleast one year");
        } else {
            alert();
        }
```